# RSS deleted entries still showing in asp.net reader after deletion from Tumblr

Tags: asp.net, webforms, rss, rss-reader

I've successfully created an ASP.NET RSS feed reader that I am using with Tumblr for a website. It works in that it grabs the most recent 3 posts. I have 6 posts to test and I deleted 3 but my reader is not showing the original three posts. It keeps showing the last 3 that were deleted. I have put the RSS in the browser for Tumblr and it shows correctly but my reader keeps showing the three posts that were deleted. I tried clearing cache and changing browsers but I still get the deleted posts in my feed. Here's the code I am using below:

**Frontend Code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvRssLI" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <div>
                    <h3><%#Eval("Title") %></h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <%#Eval("PublishDate" , "{0:d}") %>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp</div>

                <div align="right">
                    <a href='<%#Eval("Link") %>' target="_blank">Read More...</a>
                </div>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code-behind Code:**

```
private void PopulateRssFeed()
{
    string rssFeedUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RssFeedUrl"];
    List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(rssFeedUrl);
    var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item").Take(3)
                 select new
                 {
                     title = x.Element("title").Value,
                     link = x.Element("link").Value,
                     pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                 });
    if (items != null)
    {
        feeds.AddRange(items.Select(i => new Feeds
        {
            Title = i.title,
            Link = i.link,
            PublishDate = i.pubDate,
        }));
    }

    gvRssLI.DataSource = feeds;
    gvRssLI.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    gvRssLI.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I think there is not enough info to give a useful answer. Are you caching the feed in a Session or ViewState? Are there any parameters in the url that might be the cause? When and where are you calling `PopulateRssFeed()`? Is there some caching in Tumblr (never used it so I don't know)?

Comment: No, I am not caching the Feed. It comes directly from the URL in my webconfig. The URL is https://iwrblog.tumblr.com/rss The browser will show just three results. But if you put that same URL in a XML parser or use the code that I have here, it still shows the three posts that were supposed to be deleted.

Comment: I tested your exact code with your feed url. As expected I only see 3 posts ("Blog Post 3", "Blog Post 2" and "Why Content is King on the Internet")

Comment: It must take a few days for the Tumblr Feed to show updates to the RSS feed that are made directly on the blog. I just re-tested and deleted two posts that had "Blog" in them to see if I would be left with one post and all three still show. The Tumblr site must be caching the results for a number of days but I have not read this anywhere. You helped me investigate the issue. If you post some type of answer, I will accept it so you get credit for helping me look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it works. The feed is displayed correctly. It seems Tumblr has long cache times. But as you say very few info can be found on that subject, the only useful hint was this url.

https://twitter.com/fromedome/status/237250951889698816

But did you know you can make strongly typed GridViews? You can use `ItemType` in the GridView and then you have access to the Class properties with `Item`. This helps with type-safety since the `Item` is already the correct datatype. You have to modify `YourNameSpace.Feeds` to your correct namespace.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvRssLI" runat="server" ItemType="YourNameSpace.Feeds">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <div>
                    <h3><%# Item.Title %></h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <%# Item.PublishDate.ToLongDateString() %>
                </div>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note: you can also use a dedicated library to read RSS feeds, like https://github.com/codehollow/FeedReader